# Java: Swing library for creating animated help overlay animations?

Tags: java, swing

Looking to create similar effect to

http://www.youtube.com/create/GoAnimate

I like the cartoon avatar which guide the user step by step with animated green arrows, explaining what to do and what the important buttons do.

Comment: why close? I'm sure there are people looking to implement such feature in their Java swing app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way IMO is to **use animation framework**. The most useful ones in swing world are

- Trident ( http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home )
- Timing Framework ( http://java.net/projects/timingframework )